# Exporting image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I'm new to GEE. I have been trying to export images with no success. The NDVI was exported but the image only appears in part on QGIS. Below are the codes I am using.

**Imports**

```
roi: Point (37.13, -3.72)
type: Point
coordinates: [37.13392699335342,-3.7217546300700697]
type: ImageCollection
id: COPERNICUS/S2
version: 1637265242122699
bands: []
properties: Object (21 properties)
```

**Codes**

```
var image = ee.Image(sent

    .filterDate("2021-01-01", "2021-09-30")
    .filterBounds(Taita_roi)
    .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT")
    .first());

var trueColour = {
        bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
        min: 0,
        max: 3000
        };

  Map.addLayer(image, trueColour, "true-colour image");
 var falseColour = {
        bands: ["B8", "B4", "B3"],
        min: 0,
        max: 3000
        };

    // Add the image to the map, using the visualization parameters.
    Map.addLayer(image, falseColour, "false-color composite");

 var NDVI = image.expression(
        "(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)",
        {
          RED: image.select("B4"),    
          NIR: image.select("B8"),    
          BLUE: image.select("B2")    
        });

    Map.addLayer(NDVI, {min: 0, max: 1}, "NDVI");

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: NDVI,
  description: 'NDVI1',
  region: Taita_roi,
  folder: 'earthengine',
  scale: 10, 
  maxPixels:1e10
})
```

Comment: @TomazizM thank you for your response. The export works but the NDVI image is just dark. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Based on the example here (which we cannot reproduce) i'd suggest to start and check if your export is indeed incorrect. Did you try and see if there is any values in your pixels (inquiry in QGIS)? Also apply a stretch to your data if you try to visualize, so manually set the range to 0-1.